# Proximity feature in Android

Tags: java, android, proximity

I was wondering how Color(the flopped company)made use of proximity features they had enabled. From what I know it's different to Geolocation as such and uses as far as I'm concerned a different approach. I'm quite new to Android&Java coding and hoping that someone would point me at a direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> So, for instance, to augment a location signal from GPS, Color will use clues like lighting and ambient noise to understand that two photos were taken in the same place. It will also try to understand which people users are interested in, and how that changes over time–so if a user hasn’t interacted with someone’s pictures for the while, that person’s icon will appear further out and darker in the user’s list of relevant people (Color calls this the “elastic network”).

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rVOQkyvBEBMJ:allthingsd.com/20110323/with-41m-in-hand-color-deploys-new-proximity-based-social-network/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Seems to me that it is location based photo sharing and they used context of the images to improve the accuracy and relevancy of groups of photos.